# why doesn't the rig follow the sphere?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

Rig beginner here:

I have a simple inverse kinematic rig here:

[image]

The sphere is the target of the IK of Bone.00

I limited the y/z rotation like this for both bones:

[image]

I do not understand, why this is the result:

[image]

In my simple understanding it should be this:

[image]

I have no idea why....How do I solve this, or what did I make wrong?

[image]

Comment: In the file you provided, for me, with positions of target like that shown, it does reach the sphere.  It doesn't reach the sphere in some positions where sphere is very, very close to to Bone.01, because it's interpreting that as requiring Z axis rotation.  I don't know why that is, but the solution is to IK lock Y and Z instead of angle limiting Y and Z to 0,0.

Comment: Oh I see, in your file, you didn't limit Bone.01, like you described in the question.  Same thing though: IK lock instead of angle limiting.

Comment: oh man....that was easy. I am really dumb. Ok, put this as answer and you got a upvote and a check for that really quick right comment/answer!